# How do I make UITextField respond to UITextFieldDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my app I have a UITextField that is instantiated as follows inside of a UITableViewController:

```
doField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: doFieldRect];
doField.delegate = self;
```

then I add it to my view with

```
[self.view addSubview: doField];
```

How do I get this subview to respond to my delegate methods in the UITableViewController? As it isn't responding to any of the methods...

Comment: You said you are using UITableViewController so when you add this textField on this controller, Is it shown properly? Because in case of UITableViewController the entire view is covered with tableview and if you try to add any other UI control on it using IB it will slip to the bottom portion with width 320.0px. In your case you are providing some frame. Please let me know whether textfield is visible or not.

Comment: The way that this is set up on the screen is that I have programmatically added a UIView above the tableview, and this UITextField lies on top of this UIView above the tableview. So what I have is a UITextField that is visible and is a subview of the UITableViewController. Is there any way to make this UITextfield respond to the UITextFieldDelegate methods?

Answer (score 1):

In your header file, you need to add the delegate:

```
@interface MyClassHeaderFile : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: the key there is the "<UITextFieldDelegate>" addition

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already added that, sorry for forgetting that key detail.